# how can i read a select using jquery?

Tags: jquery, select

I want to read the values from a select dropdown in jquery and populate into an array of objects where each object has a Text property and a Value property.

What is the best way to do this using jquery?

Comment: Yes, its definitely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd want to select on the options in a select, then loop them with `$.each`

```
var options = [];
$("select option").each(function(i, val){
    var $val = $(val);
    options.push({ text: $val.text, value: $val.val() });
});
```

Or, you can more succinctly use `$.map`:

```
var options =  $.map($("select option"), function(val){
    var $val = $(val);
    return { text: $val.text(), value: $val.val() };
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a4PFN/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var choices = [];
$("select option").each(function(index, element) {
    var $i = element;
    choices.push({ $i.text, $i.val() })
}
```